# sound absorption material for home cinema

Tags: home-theater, audio

So I've started my home cinema project, read a ton of websites and have the basics planned.

What I don't know yet, and the Internet is full of conflicting opinions, is what the best material for sound absorption is?

I will line the walls and the ceiling with wood frames, like this:
[image]

The front will be covered with fabric. Inside the frame I want to put my sound absorbers. Obviously, accoustic foam or special absorbers would be best, but I have a fairly large room and a limited budget. I would rather line the walls and ceiling with something that's 80% good and reserve some budget for putting professional absorbers in one or two key spots.

So, on a budget, and a depth of about 5 cm (2 inches), which is the best choice for material to put there?

**Additional information:**

It's a basement room, so the walls by themselves are already thick and isolated and I'm not worried about the neighbours, I only care about the accoustics inside the room.

The 5cm depth of the frame is an arbitrary choice, if I get significantly better sound by going to 8 cm (the next depth I can get wood for easily) then that's an option. More is not as my screen is already installed and has about 10 cm space on each side.

I also plan to run the wires through/behind those frames, and put the front and rear speakers partially inside.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pABvTWSxOes test several materials. spoiler: towels work best. it does seem though, that you want sound proofing, which is different.

Comment: will be tricky to get so many towels. :-)

Comment: @Tom Do you have second-hand stores around?  That's always a good source of cheap material.  I would be concerned of the fire hazard that all those towels present, but there are [some methods of fireproofing](https://www.wikihow.com/Make-Cloth-Fireproof).

Comment: also, get rid of that tile floor and throw down a carpet.

Answer (score 2):

I was just told recently by someone who took a class on something involving building sound absorption panels, that recycled denim material makes an excellent sound deadener.

He said to wrap the bats of denim in speaker material and hang them an inch or so away from the wall to kill echo or noise from another room.

Good luck with your home theater.

Comment: any idea where to get such material cheaply?

Comment: They make an insulation out of denim. You may try the search for it.